# BufferedImage to InputStream - Format is different

Tags: java, inputstream, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I am trying to convert my BufferedImage to an Inputstream using the following:

```
BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(file.getInputStream());
bi = Scalr.resize(bi, 300);
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(bi, file.getContentType(), os); //the content type is specified as image/jpeg
```

The problem I am facing is that my `file.getContentType()` returns the value as "image/jpeg" instead of e.g. "jpg", and thus shows a corrupt file.

Is there a good way to convert this to jpg (or make it possibly accept image/jpeg)? I have many other file formats (png for instance) and think that a switch statement which does some logic to check what the content type is would be quite unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.jpeg` and `.jpg` are equivalent extensions - `jpg` exists due to the historic requirements of Windows to have an 8.3 filename.extension format.

To get the necessary extension, pull it out of the content type:

```
final String contentType = file.getContentType();
contentType.substring(contentType.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)
```

Comment: Actually, the file extension is irrelevant in this case. The parameter sent to `ImageIO.write` is an informal "format name". Any of `"JPEG"`, `"JPG"`, `"jpeg"` or `"jpg"` will do.